# Change Color of Circle in HTML Canvas Pong Animation on Paddle Hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using a simple canvas layout and am trying to figure out how I can modify a pong script so that it changes the color of the ball to red each time it hits to paddle and blue each time it misses.

The canvas setup is the same as on this web page:

[Informit Canvas for Gaming](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2424802)

I am using Context.strokeStyle to change the color but it is not working in the context I've placed it.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;" />
    <script src="JQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</BODY>
```

Javascript for pong elements on canvas:

```
    var Main = {};                                      // scope a (global) main object

Main.Canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');                  // 600 x 600 canvas (per HTML)
Main.Context = Main.Canvas.getContext('2d');                         
Main.MX = 0;                                        // keep track of X mouse position
Main.MY = 0;    

Main.CX = 395;
Main.CY = 150;      
Main.CRAD = 20;

Main.XINC = 1;  
Main.YINC = 1;  
Main.OFFSET = 1;    

Main.HITS = 0;
Main.MISSES = 0;

// keep track of mouse movements
Main.Canvas.onmousemove = function(event)
{
    if (event.offsetX)
    {
        mouseX = event.offsetX;
        mouseY = event.offsetY;
    }
    else if (event.layerX)
    {
        mouseX = event.layerX;
        mouseY = event.layerY;
    }

    Main.MX = mouseX;
    Main.MY = mouseY;
}

Main.Animate = function()
{
    Main.Context.clearRect(0, 0, Main.Canvas.width, Main.Canvas.height);        // clear entire canvas
                                            // upper left X & Y coordinates, width & height

    // Draw Rectangle
    Main.Context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";                         // color red
    Main.Context.fillRect(0, Main.MY, 25, 50);                  // position and size (follow mouse)

    // Draw Circle
    Main.Context.beginPath();                           // start the circle

    // When ball crosses the paddle width, 
    // check to see if paddle intersects path
    if ( (Main.CX-Main.CRAD == 25) && (Main.XINC == -1) ) {

        // if ball hits paddle, change increment (both X & Y) and change color of circle
        if ( (Main.CY>Main.MY) && (Main.CY<(Main.MY+50)) ){

            Main.XINC = Main.XINC * (-1);
            Main.YINC = Main.YINC * (-1);

            Main.HITS = Main.HITS + 1;
            Main.Context.beginPath();
            Main.Context.strokeStyle = 'red';

        } else Main.MISSES = Main.MISSES + 1;
        Main.Context.beginPath();
            Main.Context.strokeStyle = 'blue';

    }

    // If we hit a wall in x coordinate, then change x direction
    if ( (Main.CX < 0+Main.CRAD) || (Main.CX > 600-Main.CRAD)) 
        Main.XINC = Main.XINC * (-1);
    Main.CX = Main.CX + (Main.XINC);    

    // If we hit a wall in y coordinate, then change y direction
    if ( (Main.CY < 0+Main.CRAD) || (Main.CY > 600-Main.CRAD)) 
        Main.YINC = Main.YINC * (-1);
    Main.CY = Main.CY + Main.YINC;  

    Main.Context.arc(Main.CX, Main.CY, Main.CRAD, 0, 2 * Math.PI);          // draw the circle
    Main.Context.stroke();                              // fill the circle

    // Display the location of the mouse and circle
    Main.Context.font = "10px Arial";
    Main.Context.fillText("Mouse: X: " + Main.MX + "  Y: " + Main.MY, 50, 25);
    Main.Context.fillText("Ball: X: " + Main.CX + "  Y: " + Main.CY, 350, 25);

    // Display the score
    Main.Context.font = "30px Arial";
    Main.Context.fillText("Hits: " + Main.HITS + "  Misses: " + Main.MISSES, 50, 100);

    requestAnimFrame(function() { Main.Animate(); });               // must call at end of Main.Animate (recursive)
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback)                       // part of sample standard framework                    
{                                           // for browser compatibilty
    return window.requestAnimationFrame
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
    || function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };      // control repainting speed
})();

$(document).ready(function()                                // called when document loads
{
    Main.Animate();                                 // this method is all that executes here
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just missing open and close `{}` brackets on your `else`, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wwg1q5j/61/

```
else{ 
        Main.MISSES = Main.MISSES + 1;
        Main.Context.beginPath();
        Main.Context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
}
```

Comment: Wow. Am I really this dumb??

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix. Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the answer already provided and the comments by the OP below that.

The most common source of bugs in programming any language are syntactic errors that can pass compilation or parsing. Javascript is particularly prone to this type of error due to it non declarative loosely typed nature. That means you don't have to declare variables, object structures, and functions, and that variable types need not be explicitly defined.

To the OP don't be surprised that you missed that bug, it is so easy to overlook, especially when the focus is on the logic of the code rather than the syntax. I will also say this will not be the last time that this same syntax bug will frustrate you.

The best way to limit syntaxical bugs is consistent style.

When you have 100s and 1000s of lines of code and your style varies over the whole thing it becomes very hard to see these types of errors, curly brackets are particularly hard to see in the mass of characters, even more so when you indent sometimes and not others, or add the curly bracket on a new line sometimes and not others. With consistency in style and some experience a bug like this will stand out and be quickly spotted.

For Javascript there are a variety of code quality tools that will help you with style. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and [JSHint](http://www.methodsandtools.com/tools/jshint.php) are two examples and many editors have these tools or similar built in. Of more importance than using such tools is understanding the rules they apply and why they apply them. They do not improve the quality of the code in terms of logic or performance, what they do is reduce bugs and make bugs easier to spot.

For the OP (and everyone for that matter) I will suggest that you forever forget the fact that Javascript allows you to drop the curly brace for `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, and `do` (The same holds true for C/C++ Java and similar languages)

Never again do

```
if(foo === bar) 
     callThat();
```

Some for need of brevity, have adopted the style that single line conditions must follow on the same line

```
if(foo === bar) callThat();
```

or

```
while(!stream.eof) buff.push(stream.read);
```

This is one style that makes it easy to spot if you have added extra code within the condition. Though this can become messy when the statement for the condition is long and you are already deep into indented code. such as

```
if((foo !== bar && foo <== poo && foo > that && what !== how) || cows === cud || day !== night || black == white) return (((u1 / r1) * ( r1 * r1 * m1 - r2 * r2 * m2 ) + 2 * r2 * r2 * m2 * (u2 / r2)) / (r1 * r1 * m1 + r2 * r2 * m2)) * r1;
```

Or if you have nested many single line conditions

```
if(foo !== bar) if(foo <== poo) if(foo > that) if(what !== how) if(cows === cud || day !== night || black == white) return sunshine();
```

Personally for the pain of two extra characters my rule is *always* have curly brackets without exception. If you follow that rule you will never again have the bug you had.

I also noticed you are inconsistent with where you place the curly brace. Sometimes on the same line sometimes on the new line.

```
if(foo === bar) 
{
    doThat();
}
```

and then

```
if(bar === foo){
    doThat()
}
```

This will also end up in making bugs harder to find because if you are not expecting a brace on the line it can be overlooked. Pick one style and stick with that style for the entire project.

With a little effort into developing your personal coding style and being consistent you will spend more time writing productive code rather than chase frustrating bugs.

Comment: Use an IDE, maybe even an IDE that understands your coding language(s)...and if you aren't using an IDE that auto-adds closing `])}` then manually type those closers in immediately when you type the `[({`. Otherwise your "missing" errors will often annoyingly be reported further down the code after the compiler finds an unintended closer.